# Get Reporting data I've pivoted into a HTML table

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I have a curent SQL query that reads as follows:

```sql
SELECT
    WEEK,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_1_total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_2_total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_3_total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_4_total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week1' AND TYPE = 'refund' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_1_refunds,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week2' AND TYPE = 'refund' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_2_refunds,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week3' AND TYPE = 'refund' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_3_refunds,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week4' AND TYPE = 'refund' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_4_refunds,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week1' AND TYPE = 'closure' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_1_closures,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week2' AND TYPE = 'closure' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_2_closures,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week3' AND TYPE = 'closure' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_3_closures,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week4' AND TYPE = 'closure' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_4_closures,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week1' AND history LIKE '%rejected%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_1_rejections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week2' AND history LIKE '%rejected%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_2_rejections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week3' AND history LIKE '%rejected%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_3_rejections,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK = '$week4' AND history LIKE '%rejected%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_4_rejections
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    YEAR = '$SafeFY' AND period = '$SafePeriod'
GROUP BY
    WEEK
```

This query works and gets me the data I want, but because of how I have done it, the data has been pivoted.

I have only done it this way, because it's the only way I know how. I would like to use the result in a PHP loop like so:

```php
echo '<table><opening tags> <etc...>'
while($Row = $Result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
//HTML table rows with $Row['stuff'] here.
}
echo '</etc...></closing tags></table> '
```

But the data is the wrong way around for printing out the table like this:

```html
| Week | Total  | Refunds | Closures | Rejections |
|  1   |   44   |    32   |   12     |     3      |
|  2   |   40   |    21   |   19     |     6      |
|  3   |   40   |    22   |   18     |     3      |
|  4   |   41   |    32   |   11     |     6      |
```

I dont' mind either changing the query to get all the same results without the pivot so I can loop over them like I am used to doing, or doing something with the PHP array so I can loop over this queries results, whichever is easier/better. How?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've looked at this again and I think I'm just making it harder than it needs to be.

Going on the following assumptions:
1) Databases are generally better at sorting/organising data than PHP, so changing the query is probably better than changing the array after the fact.
2)If I want the result to have 5 columns, I probably need to have five selects in the statement,

Then I looked at the GROUP BY part and realised it's already going to split the results by week anyway, so I trimmed down by sums and the GROUP BY part will then allow the results to be split into weeks already, there was no need to sum each week manually in the select part.

```sql
SELECT
    WEEK,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR = '2019' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'refund' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS refunds,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'closure' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS closures,
    SUM(CASE WHEN history LIKE '%rejected%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rejections

FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    YEAR = '$SafeFY' AND period = '$SafePeriod'
GROUP BY
    WEEK
```